# More than 1 client in a udp echo server

Tags: c, udp, udpclient

I have a UDP echo client and server program. As im trying to connect more than one client to connect to the server using different computers i'm getting a positive response , that is im being able to connect my server with more than one client.

So, my question is, when I break ctrl+c to break the server, I want to print the ip addresses of all the clients which are associated with the server at that time.
How do I do it? I know how to print the IP address when a single client is connected to a server, but how do I print for more than one client?

Comment: There are a few problems with what you want; First of all "overloading" the `CTRL-C` to do something that its not supposed to do will make your program seem very odd, and how would you cancel/kill the program? Secondly, as it's UDP you don't really have *connections* from clients, but you can still keep a list of all clients that's communicating with the server. As for catching `CTRL-C`, do a search for the terms *signal* and *break*.

Comment: UDP is connectionless. There is no "client connected to server" concept in UDP. You can print/store each client IP at every UDP communication, any UDP message contains the sender's info (IP+port). If you use `recvfom`, there is parameter which can be filled with these infos. See: http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any build-in mechanism to do it. UDP is connectionless, so sockets don't "remember" who they communicated with.

To print all clients your server communicated with you need to keep track of them yourself. You'd probably need a set (you can find some open source implementations of sets in C if you don't want to build one yourself) or even a simple linked list might do, depending on your case. After each `recvfrom`, add the client to the set/list. After you're done processing each request, remove the client from the set/list.

Then you need to set up a handler to react to ^C. In it you just print the set/list.